# How to reverse a string in Burp Intruder's payload processing?

Tags: payload, burp

I'm using Burp Intruder to enumerate through a bunch of numbers, encode them, reverse them, and feed them to the testing system. Normally I can choose some payload processors to auto-generate the tested payload values, but there is no such choice as "reversing the payload string". There is a "reverse substring", which is essentially picking a substring from the back of the payload values (not what I want). How can I add a process to reverse my payload value?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Install *Hackvertor* plugin
2. In the Intruder Position tab wrap the insertion point with a  tag

   ```
   username=administrator&password=<@reverse>§test§<@/reverse>
   ```
3. Start the attack

You will not see the reverse payload in the Intruder attack window but if you check the Logger tab the payload is indeed reversed.

[image]